# Android Studio : cannot find symbol variable

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my `login.xml`.

[image]

This is my java file. There are no red marks in my java file, but it is showing error while compiling.

[image]

In the following lines.

```
textButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TextButton);
fingerprintButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.FingerprintButton);
```

I keep getting this error:

> Error:(52, 48) error: cannot find symbol variable TextButton
>
> Error:(53, 55) error: cannot find symbol variable FingerprintButton

I have declared these vairables and included the in `string.xml` as well. I am new to android studio. Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure that there are Buttons, which is named TextButton and FingerprintButton, in your xml files? (I guess xml file name would be activity_main.xml)

Comment: yes, I am sure.

Comment: share your xml code as well as java code images are not visible

Comment: How about checking your javaSE?

Comment: have you tried by changing ids with small caps?

Comment: yes I've tried.

Comment: The error is gone. I created another java file and copied the contents of `Login.java` in it. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

emmm...here you want to access IDs of `Button` right? In Android arch, ids are defined in `R.java` and no need to edit anything because Android Studio would generate automatically. Things you need to do is simply add your `id` in your `layuot.xml`, with a xml tag names `android:id='@+id/textButton'` under a Button tag. Not `String.xml`.

Comment: I have added the buttons in my login.xml file in layout with the IDs TextButton and FingerprintButton.

Comment: please check your import, is the R file from your project instead other?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the buttons as `text_button` and `fingerprint_button` in your `login.xml`. Then make the changes accordingly in your `LoginActivity.java` like the following.

```
textButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.text_button);
fingerprintButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fingerprint_button);
```

Clean and rebuild your application.

Comment: Did you clean the application? Go to Build option in the top of Android Studio and then find Clean. Clean the project and rebuild the project again.

Comment: Yes I did everything you told me.

Comment: Please share the code for `login.xml` and the `LoginActivity.java` instead of sharing pictures of them. Then I could debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public Button textButton, fingerPrintButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    textButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textButton);
    fingerPrintButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fingerPrintButton);

    textButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    fingerPrintButton.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == textButton)
    {
        //Your Custom Code
    }
    else if(v == fingerPrintButton)
    {
        //Your Custom Code
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried the code above, I got 2 errors instead of 4. So, can it be because of `findViewById`? If it is possible, then what other alternative can I use? I tried to use Binding but things got complicated.

Comment: In the snippets I added, there were 4 errors for cannot find symbol, 2 for each button. Now I have 2 errors, 1 for each button.         `Error:(40, 50) error: cannot find symbol variable text_button`                                                                                           `Error:(41, 57) error: cannot find symbol variable fingerprint_button`